# Summation and production using hold

Tags: syntax, summation, products

Let's take a sum and an example production

$z_{1}=\sum_{k=1}^{3}(k!+(k+1)!)$

and

$z_{2}=\prod_{k=1}^{3}(k!+(k+1)!)$

I wish to get in `z1`

a result like that

$z_{1} =(1! +(1+1)!)+ (2!+(2+1)!)+(3!+(3+1)!)$

likewise for `z2` such a result

$z_{2} =(1! +(1+1)!)(2!+(2+1)!)(3!+(3+1)!)$

I used different variations of `Hold` but could not come up with anything
help me a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Inactivate[Sum[Factorial[k] + Factorial[1 + k], {k, 1, 3}], Factorial|Plus]
```

> (1! + (1 + 1)!) + (2! + (1 + 2)!) + (3! + (1 + 3)!)

```
Inactivate[Product[Factorial[k] + Factorial[1 + k], {k, 1, 3}], Factorial|Plus]
```

> (1!+ (1 + 1)!) (2! + (1 +2 )!) (3! + (1 + 3)!)

Comment: thanks , thanks for the information, I had not seen that instruction